# I want to change only position

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c++, box2d-iphone

I move my body with box2d in cocos2d.I want to change only position.But, not angle(not rotation). it changing the angle at during moving. When I set with SetTransform method, everytime same angle.

ı captured to my problem on youtube :  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQAQtgplLmw&feature=youtu.be

**My Code:**

```
body->SetTransform(myB2Vec2Position, body->GetAngle());
```

**before set My body**

[image]

** image2: after set My body with SetTransform **

[image]

**Like image2  : it changed the angle at moving When I set with SetTransform method everytime same angle.**

[image]

---

```
 NSLog(@"MyAngleValue: %f",currentBody->GetAngle());
```

**Everytime** : MyAngleValue:0.000000    . Normally , my body change Angle everytime.when I call SetTransform method , angle is be 0.000000  .   **What is problem ?**

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When setting your body definition, try setting this parameter as well:

```
bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
```

Comment: I changed bodyDef.fixedRotation = true; but. my problem did't solve

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your body to spin at all (never, no matter what) set its momentum to `INFINITY`. That should do it (if you don't manually changed the angle or angular velocity).

Comment: I want to spin my body. But my problem is different. a few minute ago  I added here. I captured on youtube : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQAQtgplLmw&feature=youtu.be